# Extra line breaks with simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textarea

To practice Ruby on Rails, I am creating a blog which includes a text area (following Mackenzie Child's tutorial). Unfortunately, line breaks are included every time I press enter. How can I remove the extra line breaks?

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<p><%= simple_format(@post.body) %></p>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form">
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end

private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

So I type the following into the text area:

```
for j in 1..array.length-1
        key = array[j]
        i = j - 1
```

But this is what posts:

```
for j in 1..array.length-1

        key = array[j]

        i = j - 1
```

And if remove simple_format, it removes all new lines, which I don't want either.

In the developer tools:

```
<p>
"   for j in 1..array.length-1
"
<br>
"         key = array[j]
"
<br>
"         i = j - 1
"
<br>
```

Comment: When you say "this is what posts", where are you looking? Are you looking at what's been stored in the database or are you looking in the browser at a page which displays your posts?

Comment: The browser which posts what I've written.

Comment: You mean for the controller's `show` action? What does the view for that action look like?

Comment: I actually wrapped the simple_format parens around the post in the show. I have updated this in my question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up a bit? So you're still seeing the double line breaks on the show page though? If you do view source in your browser, what does the HTML that's been generated for the post text look like?

Comment: Check the bottom of the question.

Comment: Hmm.. the HTML looks ok, as in just single br tags. Do you actually get the indentation for the `key =` and `i =` lines because I wouldn't expect them to be indented if using just `simple_format` to format the text, so if they are indented then sounds like something else is affecting the way it displays?

Comment: Yeah. I just did a test without using normalize, and I had the same results. But I think the fact that the break tags are there is what the problem is. It's putting them every time I press enter, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to assume, that because you are wrapping the body content in show.html.erb, that you don’t mind the data in your database but just want to clean it up to present it.

Have you tried:

```
<p><%= strip_tags @post.body %></p>
```

[Rails API Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding the question, but I think you're getting confused about the purpose of `simple_format`.

`simple_format` takes some text that has line breaks in it and formats it as basic HTML by replacing 2 or more line breaks as paragraphs and single line breaks as `<br>` tags. This is what you would use to display a post to a visitor to the blog.

When you want the text of an existing blog post in a `textarea` then you want to leave the line breaks in the text intact, which is achieved using `<%= f.text_area :body %>` without wrapping in a  call to `simple_format`.

Comment: But if I remove simple format, it takes out all lines. I edited my post at the bottom to specify what I meant.